# SharePoint 2013 Search - Mapped Property appears in one site collection not another?

Tags: search, crawled-property

I have a crawled property that I've mapped to a managed property.  I'm having issues surfacing it in a search result.

The strange thing in one site collection the crawled property is mapped.  However when I view the property from a different site collection it is not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you create the mapped property? In Central Administration or in a site?

Comment: In Site Settings for a site collection.  In the other Site Collection, I don't have access to the map property setting.